# Where does the equation $E_q = \frac{kq}{r^2}$ come from in this problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-fields

> A point charge is placed at each corner of a square with side length
> $a$. The charges all have the same magnitude $q$. Two of the charges
> are positive and two are negative, as shown in the following figure.
>
> What is the magnitude of the net electric field at the center of the
> square due to the four charges in terms of $q$ and $a$?

I'm trying to understand this question by using the solution my instructor gave me, but I'm confused.

I found $r=\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}$, which makes sense. However then it says:

> The magnitude of the electric field due to each charge is the same and equal to
>
> $$E_q = \frac{kq}{r^2} = \frac{2kq}{a^2}$$

How did they come up with this? I only know the equations $F = \frac{k\lvert q_1q_2\rvert}{r^2}$ and $E = \frac{F_0}{q_0}$ and I can't seem to work out how they got to this point.

Comment: I just wanted to say, I consider this an excellent example of how to ask a homework question :-)

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky It could use the referenced diagram, though, since there are two distinct ways to put the charges on a square resulting in two different answers to the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you have is correct. It's just an algebra step to get to the final answer.

You already have
$$r = \frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}$$
Squaring it, you get
$$r^2 = \frac{a^2}{2}$$
Now use this to make a substitution for $r^2$ in your equation for the electric field strength
$$\frac{k q}{r^2} = \frac{kq}{a^2/2} = \frac{2 k q}{a^2}$$

Comment: Now that I see it, I get it. Perfect answer!

Answer (score 0):

The equation comes if you put q1=q0 in the equations you have mentioned.